# Is there a way to check if a get request (made using requests module in python3) did pop an alert box?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, command-line-interface

So I am making a sort of Automated script which basically bruteforces a bunch of payloads to check a SSTI vulnerability on Flask/Jinja2 Applications. However certain payloads include an `alert` syntax. How do I check if an alert box was popped upon the request  **WITHOUT USING SELENIUM** ?

PS : I am trying to *strictly* limit it to be a CLI based application so no GUI stuff :)

Comment: You cannot check if an alert box popped up, requests simply sends requests.

Comment: Selenium can also be run with a headless browser

Comment: Requests fetches the resources identified by URLs.  It doesn't render HTML, much less execute Javascript.

Comment: Use selenium, `driver.switch.to_alert()`

Comment: I was hoping for a way to check if I could check for the alert pop up, nothing much, just a simple Boolean value would do @JoshuaNixon

Comment: Well is there any method to check for a pop up using python3 ? @snakecharmerb

Comment: Can you elaborate on that @GuiHva , please ?

Comment: Refer this, <https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/>